# NoMethodError: undefined method `ids' for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As per [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_querying.html) we can use ids insted of pluck(:id). As per that guide I tried *User.ids* it works fine but when I tried it with *User.first(5).ids* it gives me "NoMethodError: undefined method `ids' for Array:0x0055ed07fc2c28" error.

As per me User.first(5) also returns an array of five user. Can you please point where I am going wrong.

```
User.limit(2)
[

    [0] #<User:0x0055ed01c295e0> {
                             :id => 275,
                           :name => "ganesh",
                          :email => "ganu@gmail.com",
             :encrypted_password => "$2a$11$lCHphhqnGFrBYr2cb3wEBORS4UphI09Gy6.eiGidXo6cnJ3SnyJ3K",
           :reset_password_token => nil,
         :reset_password_sent_at => nil,
            :remember_created_at => nil,
                  :sign_in_count => 0,
             :current_sign_in_at => nil,
                :last_sign_in_at => nil,
             :current_sign_in_ip => nil,
                :last_sign_in_ip => nil,
                     :contact_no => "+91123456486",
                     :created_at => Thu, 16 Feb 2017 13:29:41 UTC +00:00,
                     :updated_at => Thu, 16 Feb 2017 13:29:41 UTC +00:00,
                     :auth_token => "s2NXHr-4LtQ5q9XUB9oC"
    },

    [1] #<User:0x0055ed01c294a0> {
                             :id => 45,
                           :name => "sagar",
                          :email => "abcabc@gmail.com",
             :encrypted_password => "$2a$11$/aEo8q7W81KYsbNYZwWY3O86p16nU3Z4XcwGyOCJGDa.ypcWk13/e",
           :reset_password_token => nil,
         :reset_password_sent_at => nil,
            :remember_created_at => nil,
                  :sign_in_count => 0,
             :current_sign_in_at => nil,
                :last_sign_in_at => nil,
             :current_sign_in_ip => nil,
                :last_sign_in_ip => nil,
                     :contact_no => "+972555558585",
                     :created_at => Mon, 26 Dec 2016 05:45:45 UTC +00:00,
                     :updated_at => Mon, 26 Dec 2016 05:45:45 UTC +00:00,
                     :auth_token => "a5fsxNNYYtwvWFm3oaGn"
    }

]




User.first(2)
[

    [0] #<User:0x0055ed01e56bb0> {
                             :id => 1,
                           :name => "vishal",
                          :email => "sagar@gmail.com",
             :encrypted_password => "$2a$11$8hfJP5N1YMK94fD6c4kLRuA4MC8qRwPM0tnHn.2IDMWwsPN/ailE2",
           :reset_password_token => "db351406653661c9bddeac1e977066e71762a08eb60925cc1b9c82ea0d922d11",
         :reset_password_sent_at => Mon, 08 May 2017 07:42:42 UTC +00:00,
            :remember_created_at => Mon, 19 Jun 2017 10:24:18 UTC +00:00,
                  :sign_in_count => 451,
             :current_sign_in_at => Wed, 27 Sep 2017 07:06:50 UTC +00:00,
                :last_sign_in_at => Wed, 27 Sep 2017 06:55:04 UTC +00:00,
             :current_sign_in_ip => "49.248.152.50",
                :last_sign_in_ip => "49.248.152.50",
                     :contact_no => "+91",
                     :created_at => Wed, 21 Dec 2016 04:51:01 UTC +00:00,
                     :updated_at => Wed, 27 Sep 2017 07:06:50 UTC +00:00,
                     :auth_token => "JT3syyUuUzPiyvha2zp4"
    },
    [1] #<User:0x0055ed01e569a8> {
                             :id => 2,
                           :name => "Chetan",
                          :email => "chetan@gmail.com",
             :encrypted_password => "$2a$11$Jgw/Sd.sBypJKnXGMBtF9OhdS7gWBy97gtmnAdEN.LG33EbyMlmbu",
           :reset_password_token => nil,
         :reset_password_sent_at => nil,
            :remember_created_at => nil,
                  :sign_in_count => 2,
             :current_sign_in_at => Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:02:26 UTC +00:00,
                :last_sign_in_at => Wed, 21 Dec 2016 14:30:33 UTC +00:00,
             :current_sign_in_ip => "49.248.250.210",
                :last_sign_in_ip => "49.248.250.210",
                     :contact_no => "",
                     :created_at => Wed, 21 Dec 2016 05:24:41 UTC +00:00,
                     :updated_at => Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:02:26 UTC +00:00,
                     :auth_token => "JaGRGPhKTxW1R-9zvUpP"
    }
]


User.first(5).class # => Array < Object
User.limit(5).class # => User::ActiveRecord_Relation < ActiveRecord::Relation
User.all.class # => User::ActiveRecord_Relation < ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Comment: `User.first(5)` returns an array, not the activerecord relation. `User.limit(5).ids` will work as you expect.

Comment: @MarekLipka I tried both User.limit(5) and User.first(5) the result of both queries were same. I can put the output for your reference let me edit the post

Comment: You can change into `User.first(5).pluck(:id)`

Comment: @Lalit please do it.

Comment: @akbarbin it won't work since `User.first(5)` returns array. `pluck` is an `ActiveRecord` method.

Comment: hmm. But I have tried `User.first(5).pluck(:id)` to Rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.4.3, it works.

Comment: Try, `User.first(5).collect(&:id)` if you want to use that `first(5)` too badly.

Comment: Oh, ok, maybe `User.first(5)` returns relation in Rails 5. So `User.first(5).ids` should work either.

Comment: I tried `User.first(5).ids` it rails 5. It didn't work also. I don't know why. It show's `NoMethodError: undefined method `ids' for #<Array:0x00005609c5b20b40>.`

Comment: @all you can check the output now

Comment: @akbarbin: yeah, because that's an array. :)

Comment: @Lalit: show `User.first(5).class` and `User.limit(5).class`. Also `User.all.class`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @Lalit: so there's your answer. `User.limit(5).ids` should work, while `User.first(5).ids` shouldn't, because these return different kinds of collections.

Comment: @MarekLipka its 5.1.4

Comment: Thanks to @SergioTulentsev I understand now whats the difference between both

Comment: @Lalit I use Rails 5.1.4 also. I tried `User.first(5).pluck(:id)`. I hope it works also.

Comment: As a side note `pluck` is also a method of `enumarable`. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20339

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in both the things, described Below:

```
User.first(5) // returns an array of first five records from user table
User.first(5).ids // returns activerecord relation object of first five     
records.
```

If still you are willing to user 'ids' you can do it by adding limit

```
User.order("id asc").limit(5).ids
```